# Synapse Notebook Rest API call to Execute a notebook with Parameters

Tags: azure-synapse

I've created a notebook with one parameter and i'm successfully exceuted the notebook by passing the parameter through notebook activity in pipeline

and i'm able to successfully run the notebook without parameters through get but now i'm trying to pass the paramtere value through rest api.but i'm unable to do so 'ive checked some of the dcuments as well but didn't find anything helpful

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are only `Create`, `Update`, `Delete`, `Get`, `Get Notebooks by Workspace`, `Get Notebook Summary by Workspace`, `Rename` Notebook these options are available.

**You can call synapse pipeline with notebook activity and pass the parameter through It by calling ‘Create Run’ REST API as a workaround**

- First create a Synapse pipeline to execute Synapse Notebook with parameters.
  [image]
- Calling pipeline run for respective pipeline using rest API
  [image]

```json
URL : https://workspacename.dev.azuresynapse.net/pipelines/pipeline name/createRun?api-version=2020-12-01

Body:{"Demo":"Pratik"}
```